# Passing relative path on OSX in C

Tags: c, macos, path

I'm trying to make a program which runs an executable in its folder on my Mac.
Considering that my program is compiled in the same folder as the source (`/Users/Marcello/Documents/C/Test/Test/Test.c`), the program would look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{

    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    if(execl("/Users/Marcello/Documents/C/Test/Test/HelloWorld", "HelloWorld", NULL))
        printf("ERROR\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine if I give the absolute path, but it won't work anymore when I try to pass the relative path to the folder (passing `"HelloWorld"` instead of `"/Users/Marcello/Documents/C/Test/Test/HelloWorld"`).

I noticed this happens because, without other indications, the program will try to search for `HelloWorld` in the shell's folder instead of the project's folder. This happens as well with functions such as `fopen()`, so I tried thinking of solutions; the problem is, I want to get this code into a program that everybody could download and install wherever they like, an I would like it to be cross-platform too, but all the solutions I found, such as `chdir()`, somehow reference to the absolute path of the program, which I shouldn't know in advance.

Can anybody help me find a long-term solution?

Comment: The program will be run with some directory as its current directory (you might use `getcwd()` to find that name).  You can either specify the program name absolutely (which you know works), or you can specify it relative to the current directory — which means you need to know the location of the program relative to the current directory.  You might use `execlp()` instead of `execl()` so that you can specify just `Helloworld` as the first argument and it will be found in a directory listed in your `$PATH` environment variable.  First debugging steps: print the value from `getcwd()`.

Comment: How do I specify `PATH` to be project's folder?

Comment: Where are you running this code from?  Inside the XCode GUI, or from a command line prompt in a terminal window, or somewhere else?  You normally arrange to install programs in known locations (I keep many of mine in `$HOME/bin`, so I have `$HOME/bin` as one of the (many) directories in my `$PATH`.  But I don't go changing `PATH` dynamically very often.  I probably wouldn't add a 'project folder' to it.  I'm not sure how to answer your question to help you.  You've left enough unspecified that I'm not sure what you're doing — or trying to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't use a fix absolute path, because **I'm not the only one** working on that project and I need it to be working also for people downloading it and installing it in **whatever directory they like**. The code I posted before was just an example, the project I need the function for is way more complex.

To answer your question, I run this program from my shell, which usually is initialized to `~/`. What I'm looking for is a way to **link directly to the project's directory**, or to **get the project's directory path** directly from the program itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element of `argv`  contain the relative to path to your program.

Comment: Yeah, but the current directory is _the shell's_ current directory. Not _the project's_ directory.

Comment: Does argv[0] contain the path you want?